# How to remove a Shimano Quick-Link?

Tags: chain, drivetrain

I'm currently repurposing an old frame and replacing the drivetrain. If possible I'd keep the old 7 speed drive train the bike had together in case I ever find a use for it. The chain is an HG40 quick-link. There's plenty of info online about joining chains with quick-links but little about breaking and reusing them.

Is there a trick to the quick link to separate the chain so it can be easily reused or do I just need to break it with a chain tool?

The install [Tech Doc](http://techdocs.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/SI/Chain/SI_0034B_001/SM-UG51/SI_0034B_13_v1_m56577569830604498.pdf) can be found here.

Comment: I didn't know Shimano made a "quick link" -- I though they were married to their throw-away pin scheme.

Comment: This is earlier than the pins I believe. I'll add the installation tech doc.

Comment: I would guess you bend the chain as for install, until one end pops loose.  But I'd suggest tossing that link and replacing with an SRAM one.  (Or toss the entire chain, if it's got any wear on it at all.  Check it with a stretch gauge.)

Comment: Or bend and pry with small screwdriver, which will take three hands (or a vice to hold one end). But otherwise, what Daniel said.

Comment: http://answers.evanscycles.com/answers/0924/product/ec007427/shimano-hg40-6-8-speed-chain-questions-answers/questions.htm

Answer (score 1):

This is a different link than the Sram type of links. Here is a link to the directions I found that includes the HG-40 Quick link. Hope this helps!

http://techdocs.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/SI/Chain/SI_0034B_001/SI-0034B-001_13_v1_m56577569830625422.pdf